Keras Fit Method 'Unrecognized Data Type' for NLP Classification Problem with TextVectorization
I have an LSTM based model.  I am using a text vectorization layer and an embedding layer prior to the LSTM layers.  I am also using two Dense layers with a softmax output.  I am trying to go for binary classification across text inputs.
Here is my code (the inputs are just examples and my larger data set looks just like them, but with far more entries).
Libraries (some not necessary for this portion of the project):
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import nltk

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
import numpy as np
import itertools
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from tabulate import tabulate
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense, Embedding, Input
from keras.layers import TextVectorization
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence

Simple inputs:
text_data = [
    "The movie was fantastic! I really enjoyed it and would watch it again.",
    "I didn't like the movie. The plot had too many holes.",
    "One of the best movies I've seen this year. Highly recommended!",
    "The acting was poor and the storyline was boring. I wouldn't recommend it."
]

labels = [1, 0, 1, 0]

Text Vectorization and Adapt:
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=9000,output_mode='int',output_sequence_length = 50,                 pad_to_max_tokens = True,vocabulary = None,standardize = "lower_and_strip_punctuation",
split = 'whitespace',ngrams = None)

vectorize_layer.adapt(text_data)


Model definition:
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(Input(shape = (1,), dtype = "string"))
lstm_model.add(vectorize_layer)
lstm_model.add(Embedding(input_dim = 9000, output_dim = 128,embeddings_initializer= 'uniform'))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, recurrent_dropout = 0.25, dropout = 0.25))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(64))
lstm_model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'softmax'))
lstm_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
lstm_model.build()
lstm_model.summary()

The model seems correct:
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ text_vectorization_25           │ (None, 50)             │             0 │
│ (TextVectorization)             │                        │               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ embedding_26 (Embedding)        │ (None, 50, 128)        │     1,152,000 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ lstm_49 (LSTM)                  │ (None, 50, 64)         │        49,408 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ lstm_50 (LSTM)                  │ (None, 64)             │        33,024 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_49 (Dense)                │ (None, 32)             │         2,080 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_50 (Dense)                │ (None, 1)              │            33 │
Call model fit:
lstm_model.fit(text_data, labels, epochs=10)

Error:
ValueError: Unrecognized data type: x=['The movie was fantastic! I really enjoyed it and would watch it again.', "I didn't like the movie. The plot had too many holes.", "One of the best movies I've seen this year. Highly recommended!", "The acting was poor and the storyline was boring. I wouldn't recommend it."] (of type <class 'list'>)
Tried converting to np arrays:
a = np.array(text_data)
b = np.array(labels)

Call model fit:
lstm_model.fit(a, b, epochs=10)

Error:
ValueError: Invalid dtype: str2368

It turned out converting to tensors worked better than numpy arrays
text_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([
"The movie was fantastic! I really enjoyed it and would watch it again.",
"I didn't like the movie. The plot had too many holes.",
"One of the best movies I've seen this year. Highly recommended!",
"The acting was poor and the storyline was boring. I wouldn't recommend it.",
])
labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 0, 1, 0])

I also had to add a GlobalAveragePooling1D layer before my first Dense layer and I had to convert the dataset to batches
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((text_data, labels))
batch_size = 2
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

then fit ends up looking like this model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
